# Date range in Excel using WORKDAY.INTL to exclude holidays

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet

I am creating a spreadsheet to show two-week intervals, excluding weekends and defined holidays. This is going to expand to next June so I want to just copy and paste all the way across.

For example:
11/9/2015-11/20/2015

I'm using:

> `=TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("2015/11/9", 0,1, $W$3:$W$28)+(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*14, "mm/dd/yy")&"-"&TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("2015/11/9", 0,1, $W$3:$W$28)+(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*14+11, "mm/dd/yy")`

With example holidays:

`11/23/2015
11/24/2015
11/25/2015
11/26/2015
11/27/2015`

Hidden away on the in the W column.

When I copy and paste across, the date ranges are increasing appropriately but they are not excluding the example holidays I have defined. If I start in the set of holidays it excludes them as they should but if I add more holidays to test, the same result. My formula was kind of just cobbled together, any help or ideas would be great. Another hangup is that coworkers want it in Google Sheets.

Comment: Just curious - I wonder if it has to do with the formatting of the holidays vs. your start date? What if you put the start date as `11/9/2015`?

Comment: I just tried swapping the date format around, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("2015/11/9", (COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*10,1, $E$13:$E$17), "mm/dd/yy")&"-"&TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("2015/11/9",(COLUMNS($A:B)-1)*9+COLUMNS($A:A)-1,1, $E$13:$E$17), "mm/dd/yy")`

---

Use the [holidays] option.

> Basic Description
>
> The Excel Workday function returns a date that is a supplied number of
>   working days (excluding weekends and holidays) ahead of a given start
>   date.
>
> The syntax of the function is: WORKDAY( start_date, days, [holidays] )
>
> where the arguments are as follows: start_date    -   The initial date,
>   from which to count the number of workdays. days  -   The number of
>   workdays to add onto start_date. [holidays]   -   An optional argument,
>   which specifies an array of dates (in addition to weekends) that are
>   not to be counted as working days.
>
> Note that the start_date and [holidays] arguments should be input as
>   either:
>
> ```
> References to cells containing dates
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> Dates returned from formulas
> ```
>
> - If you attempt to input these date arguments as text, there is a risk that Excel may misinterpret them, due to different date systems,
>     or date interpretation settings.

[SOURCE](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Workday-Function.html)

Comment: I tried that out with the same result as WORKDAY.INTL

After the first two weeks 11/9/2015-11/20/2015 the next set of two weeks starts on 11/23/2015. If I am interpreting this right, that week should be excluded because it is defined as a holiday and the next range should start on 11/30/2015.

Comment: I think it excludes the dates as it should but if you have it as a start_date it can not exclude it.  Might look into that?  Not sure,  I can't access google sheets from here but I'll play with it in excel some.

Comment: From what I have seen it does the opposite of that a little. If you set the start date as one of the holidays, the date range it displays will exclude that date and shift accordingly, but as you progress with more holidays, they just show up.

Comment: `+(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*14` and `+(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*14+11` are the problems.  The workday function is working correctly but then you are taking that date and adding value to it AFTER it has correctly done its part.  You also aren't actually counting any days inside the workday function as you have it set to 0.  Have to tackle the problem differently....still working on it.

Comment: OK I thought it was something like that, I just didn't know how to word it. for the workday function I thought the number I have as 0 would be how many days from that date it would start, since I wanted it to start on that date I set it to 0.

Comment: See above I think i figured it out.

Comment: Not quite, though it does look like it's coming together. I would like the range to be from a Monday to a Friday every two weeks.    '11/09/15-11/20/15' would be the first. Then the next range would be 11/23/15-12/04/15 except that starting 11/23 is a holiday week etc. so because of the holiday week the next range should be 11/30/15-12/11/15. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: `=TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("2015/11/9", (COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*10,1, $E$13:$E$17), "mm/dd/yy")&"-"&TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("2015/11/9",(COLUMNS($A:B)-1)*9+COLUMNS($A:A)-1,1, $E$13:$E$17), "mm/dd/yy")`  Best 2 out of 3?